# how i can pass javascript varriable value to php

Tags: javascript, php

I want the JavaScript variable `res` value in a PHP variable. I have tried sending the value into a hidden field but it does not work. How can i get the value so that it can be used in PHP?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            H5P.externalDispatcher.on('xAPI', function (event) {
                if (event.data.statement.result.response == undefined && event.data.statement.result.completion == true) {
                    alert("Topic has been completed");
                    res = 1;
                }
            });
        }, 1000)
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Posting an `input type="hidden"` very much *does* "work".  What did you try and in what specific way did it "not work"?  Are you looking to post this with a form, send it via AJAX, something else?  Please be specific.

Comment: i have tried to set the value of hidden field in JavaScript but the value is not appearing in field.may be i did not set the value properly.can you explain how it is possible through hidden field

Comment: It is possible by setting the value of the hidden field and posting the form.  Nobody here can tell you what's wrong with the code that you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

### You can't.

`JavaScript` and `PHP` are totally different things. JavaScript executes on Client side and `PHP` gets executed on server side. So when `PHP` is getting executed it doesn't even know anything about JavaScript.

### Workaround

Use **AJAX** requests to send Client/JavaScript data to Server/PHP for processing.